# How to implement biometrics match-on-card on native smart card?

Tags: native, matching, smartcard, biometrics

I have a native smart card with native OS and I would like to integrate biometrics match-on-card on it.

Am I able to do it without any interaction with native smart card manufacturer?

I know that this can be easily achieved on java smart card as it has biometrics API since version 2.2.2, but this is not my case.

The native card is STARCOS card.

What could be my options?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have no other choice than to contact G+D and ask. (I would guess, that the chances for co-operation are more on the slim slide: native OS don't benefit from a firewall, so protection of their intellectual property or even the security of the resulting system is on stake).

For native cards you need **substantial** documentation and a library, which you can link to your software to make the OS addresses known (e. g. the I/O buffer, routine for allocating memory etc.). Adding a new algorithm is an advanced task: you need to access the file system to find the biometric template, another access to get the parameters of your matching algorithm, the I/O buffer for the verification data and much more.

Comment: I would like to add that the Biometrics API in javacard does NOT mean that every javacard supports on-card biometric matching! This is an optional feature and you have to check the vendor/manufacturer before ebuying cards.